# Merge the two lists to get the desired output in python

Tags: python

List1 = [th,sk,is,bl]
List2=[ue,None,y,e]

Output = the sky is blue

Merge the two given lists and combine their elements to get the desired output.

Comment: SO isn't a coding service, try something and come back if you have a concrete issue you need help with.

Comment: What is the logic to get expected output and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use `zip` and list comprehension to acomplish that:

```
List1 = ['th','sk','is','bl']
List2=['ue',None,'y','e']
temp = list(zip(List1, List2[::-1]))
words = [i[0]+i[1] for i in temp]
words = [''.join(item for item in i if item) for i in temp]
" ".join(item for item in words)
```

the `List2[::-1]` is to reverse the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some I just wrote, not sure if it is the most pythonic but here goes:

```
List1 = ["th","sk","is","bl"]
List2 = ["ue",None,"y","e"]

concat = ""
for i in range(len(List1)):
    concat += List1[i]
    if List2[len(List2)-1-i]: concat += List2[len(List2)-1-i]
    concat += " "
print(concat)
```

Expected output:

```
the sky is blue
```

I get:

```
>>> print(concat)
the sky is blue
>>>
```

But as mentioned, the purpose of this site is to teach and not do. Therefore:

```
List1 = ["th","sk","is","bl"]
List2 = ["ue",None,"y","e"]
concat = ""
```

We start by defining our lists and our "concatenation" variable, in which the parts are added.

```
for i in range(len(List1)):
```

This works round all items in List1 - I could have just typed 4, but this makes expandability in the future easy.

```
concat += List1[i]
```

List1 is in the correct order, and arrays start at 0. Hence first we have [0], the first item, to [3], the last.

```
if List2[len(List2)-1-i]: concat += List2[len(List2)-1-i]
```

Because there is a None in List2, we can’t concatenate a NoneType to a string. Therefore, we test if it is actually a value (just do “if string:”). If it is, we append it to our concatenation variable. The reason why I do len(List2)-1-i:

List2 is 4 long
We start with i=0

```
4-1-0 = 3
4-1-1 = 2
4-1-2 = 1
```

And finally,
    4-1-3=0

You will notice that these are the same indexes we used in List1, but backwards which is what List2 is.

```
concat += “ “
```

We add a space in between words, and finally;

```
print(concat)
```

We print out our result